# Efficient way to format curly braces to be inline

Tags: vim

What is the quickest way to move curly braces to be on the same line?

from this:

```
const value = { 
    input: 123 
}
```

to this:

```
const value = { input: 123 }
```

The way I do it is by using Visual with a combination of hjkl.

Bonus: How can I achieve the edits but the other way around?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Place cursor at or before the first `{`.
2. Press <kbd>v</kbd>, then <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>%</kbd>.
3. Press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>.

Note: the behavior may break if unpaired `{` or `}` exists in comment/string/etc.

Answer (score 3):

Put cursor at first line (`const...`) and then press <kbd>J</kbd> repeatedly until all the code is on one line.

If you haven't bound <kbd>Caps lock</kbd> to anything else, you can press it before to avoid holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

For a more automated way of transforming code in both directions, consider my "splitjoin" plugin: https://github.com/andrewradev/splitjoin.vim

Being a single mapping, it would, technically, be the quickest way :)